# Alternatives for Radio Button List for 'large' select areas/touch?

Tags: selection, radio-buttons

I'm looking for some examples for ways to deal with having a user select an item from a list when that list:

- may have large amounts of text (perhaps a term + a definition so a paragraph or two)
- is touch-friendly (radio buttons aren't always intuitive that you don't have to click the actual radio button which is a small target via mouse or touch)

The latter criteria has been resolved on mobile fairly well with select lists.

Is that a suitable solution for a UI that will also be used on the desktop? Are select list UI's intuitively 'selectable' via a mouse?

Comment: Sounds a lot like [card view](https://www.google.com/search?q=card+view), no?

Comment: I think card view is certainly an option!

Comment: @DA01 Can you give some sample of the data your list will contain? Is it just paragraphs of text, or are there media (image and video) items too? Also, how much of it should be visible in the single view (if there is any such restriction)?

Comment: @rk in this case, it'll be a term, plus that term's definition (typically 1 paragraph of text)

Comment: @DA01 Is searching for the term possible (from user's point of view)?

Comment: @rk that is an option (one can filter the list via search). The catch is that these are technical/industry terms that don't necessarily mesh to user's casual terms. Honestly, this is really a language problem, but, alas, that's out of our hands, so we're trying to make the best of things. The thought is that a lot of users are going to have to 'browse' through the list to find a term that matches their needs.

Comment: @DA01 You can look into contextual grouping of the terms. Basically, you need to create meta-data like tags or something which the user can use as filters to narrow down the scope to search for the term which he/she is looking for. You can have multiple level hierarchy: Computer -> Laptop -> Apple -> Thunderbolt etc.

Comment: @rk yep, that's actually our proposed 'A' solution. But at the moment, for various (typical corporate) reasons we're having to go with a plan-B.

Comment: Can you provide an example for a card view?

Comment: @DvirAdler [This](http://www.syncfusion.com/Content/en-US/Products/Images/wpf/card-view/CardView.png) is typical card view. Also just google it (in images), there's plenty of good example.

Answer (score 3):

I think Card View is an option, but it is not the best for text rich data items.

To reach efficient text browsing task (beyond search tools), designer could provide and suggest means, that minimize user cognitive and mental load. Among them are:

- **comfortable font size and line width** for easy text reading
- **simplified layout** that has no distracting elements
- **narrowed flow** that leads user through items and prevents accidental items missing
- **flow pitstops** for user to take rest as text-processing task is tedious
- **easy checking** by making the whole area clickable

Also I think checkbox behavior is better option than radio. In text browsing task user can not be sure he selected right item until he reached the end of the list. So checkboxes allow to mark suited items along the way and finally pick the most appropriate among them. It is like breaking the task to rough tuning and then fine tuning.

So my suggestions are on the pictures.

**Flow organization**
[image]
**Layout and interaction**
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a Card view as mentioned by Vitaly Mijiritsky sounds like the best route to go. However, I think you should consider not putting too much text on the cards. Two paragraphs of text on every card will quickly amount to a wall of text. Would it be an option to limit the amount you show directly, and only show the full text when selecting the item or something along those lines? The card could expand to accommodate the full text.

Doing this will also prevent layout issues where you might need to show big cards for all items only because one item has a lot of content, resulting in lots of empty space on the other cards.